# Python: How to not get a deadlock for this simple functionality?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have implemented a simple class called **Saver** that has two functions that its callers can execute.
They are **save_all()** and **save_one()**

As the name implies, when I execute save_all(), I want it to execute the function save_one() in a loop.
I just want to ensure that only one caller can execute either save_all() or save_one() at a given time from outside.

```
import asyncio

class Saver:
  def __init__(self):
    # it's lock
    self.lock = asyncio.Lock()


  def save_all():
     yield from self.lock.acquire()
     for i in range(3):
        save_one(i)
     self.lock.release()

  def save_one():
     yield from self.lock.acquire()
     print(i)
     self.lock.release()
```

Now what happens is that if I call the save_all(), it acquires the lock, and the save_one() print() statement is never executed.

How do I ensure that only caller can call either save_all() or save_one() from outside:

```
saver = Saver()
saver.save_all()
```

Comment: Either coordinate with a separate flag that `save_one` shouldn't try to acquire another lock, or use separate locks for `save_one` and `save_all`.

Comment: Does `save_all` actually need the lock? Also, you probably want to use `threading.Lock` if you aren't using the locks inside asyncio coroutines.

Comment: @dirn `threading.Lock` is not the correct tool because it will block the event loop while waiting to acquire the lock (possibly causing deadlock). The OP does appear to use the lock in asyncio code, apparently using the `yield from` syntax.

Comment: @user4815162342 but OP doesn’t appear to be using the `coroutine` decorator.

Comment: @dirn That's a good point, but on the other hand, the OP omits `self` from parameter lists but uses it in the function bodies, calls methods as if they were top-level functions, and so on. The code shown is presumably just an approximation of the OP's actual code, which I'd expect to include the decorator because it's copy-pasted from an obsolete tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The print in `save_one()` is not executed in the code as shown because the code never awaits `save_one()`, it just calls it. (But the code has other trivial flaws, so perhaps it's meant more like pseudo-code.) Also note that yield-from coroutines are deprecated, so you should use `async def` and `await` in place of `def` and `yield from` when writing async Python.

Since asyncio doesn't come with a reentrant lock, the simplest way to fix the issue is to lock only in API entry points. The underlying implementation methods can completely avoid locking, it being taken care of at the system boundaries. Then there is no deadlock because the internal `_save_all` will call the internal `_save_one`, and the lock will be acquired only once (in `save_call`, before invoking `_save_all`, or in `save_one`, before invoking `_save_one`, as the case may be):

```
class Saver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def save_all(self):
        async with self.lock:
            await self._save_all()

    async def save_one(self):
        async with self.lock:
            await self._save_one()

    async def _save_all(self):
        # private method, must be invoked with the lock held
        for i in range(3):
            await self._save_one(i)

    async def _save_one(self, i):
        # private method, must be invoked with the lock held
        print(i)
```